# Does PySpider have click or set value api in scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, pyspider

while scraping many times we need to set some value on end site and then need to click on search for more results .

Comment: If you need to interact with sites, you would typically use selenium for that

Comment: Welcome to SO, @dheeraj-mittal. Congrats on your first post. Please have a look on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) though. It is also very helpful to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).